# Is there a special name (like HEAD, FETCH_HEAD) for the root commit on the current branch in a git repository?

Tags: git, version-control

I find myself referring to the root commit for various reasons.  I usually make a tag called `first` or `root` to make it easier, but I have been dealing with quite a few repositories lately and even this manual tagging is getting quite tedious.

Is there an easy way to refer to the root commit, something similar to `HEAD` or `FETCH_HEAD`?

Comment: 1. Really, what for? 2. There is not always such a thing, but you can pretend if you always choose the first parent.

Comment: What are those "various reasons"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only see tagging that first commit relevant for you as the only current solution.
That way, you can refer to it through a well named tag instead of looking for its SHA1 through the log.

Note: there can be several "root" commits in a Git repo (i.e. several commits without any parent)
See for instance [this thread](http://lists-archives.org/git/687297-on-git-1-6-novice-s-opinion.html), with [Jakub Narębski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-narebski)'s answer:

> Not to mention that you can have multiple roots (multiple commits with no parent) in git repository.
>   Besides independent branches (like '`man`', '`html`' or '`todo`') it is usually result of absorbing or subtree-merging other projects.
>   In '`master`' branch there are 5 roots or more: joined '`git-tools`' (`mailinfo` / `mailsplit`), absorbed `gitweb`, and subtree-merged `gitk` and `git-gui`.

Answer (score 3):

To find SHA-1 identifiers of **all** root commits (starting with any local branch) in a git repository, you can use the following command:

```
$ git rev-list --parents --all |
  grep -v ' '
```

You can then use `git show` to examine them.

---

***Explanation:*** [`git rev-list`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) option `--parents` makes it print *space separated* list of all parents of the commit (in the form "commit parent…").  Therefore if a commit has any parents, the line from `git rev-list` invocation contains at least one space separating commit id from its parent id(s).

The option `--all` means that `git rev-list` works as if all the refs in `refs/` are listed on the command line as <*commit*>.

Answer (score 1):

Not so easy, but you can get the sha of the "root" that corresponds to HEAD (head's parent's parent's parent's ... parent until a commit is reached that has no parent) using

```
git rev-list --topo-order --reverse HEAD | head -n 1
```

Works for any commit actually. If there are multiple convergent paths of history, you'll get the root of the path that has the most commits in it.

I can't say that I see any use whatsoever for it, though. Most things that have any reason to traverse history an unlimited depth into the past already know how.

Comment: Note also that there might be more than one root (parentless) commit in a git repository; the above invocation would find one of them.