# Is it possible to open up only certain files/folders in my private GitHub repo for read/write access to some people?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

I'm looking for web designers, and would like to provide them RW access to certain frontend files only (html, erb files etc). I do not want them to have access to the core of my application on GitHub. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since those frontend files are directly related to your core app, the [submodule](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.htmls) solution (isolating those files in submodules) would be too cumbersome.

A possible solution, **if you don't want them to see at all your files in the core section**, would be to setup a second private independent repo, initialized with only your frontend files.
There would be no direct link between the two repos, but at least:

- your developers could push modifications to that second repo
- you could regularly [extract as patches](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_and_email.html) any evolutions and apply those to your local repo (before pushing them to your first private repo)
- or you could extract as patches your own evolutions made on those same files by you, and apply them to the second repo.

If you don't mind them to see the core files, but only want to prevent any modifications in the core app, then [Mark Longair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223092/mark-longair)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114381/is-it-possible-to-open-up-only-certain-files-folders-in-my-private-github-repo-fo/5114647#5114647) is your solution.

---

Note: [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223092/mark-longair) reminds me in the comments below that a [Git repo can have **multiple roots**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836040/is-there-a-special-name-like-head-fetch-head-for-the-root-commit-on-the-curren/3836487#3836487) (multiple commits with no parent).

That means, instead of communicating through mails and patches, you actually can import directly the `master` branch of the second repo directly in your first private repo, **as an independent branch** (a branch with no common history with your current base code).

From there, you can `cherry-pick` the commits you want to apply to your own code, or you can cherry-pick your own evolution to that independent branch, before pushing it back to the second repo (the one for the developers to work on).

Comment: Surely you don't need to extract them as patches, though - if the paths to the frontend files are the same in the cut-down frontend repo and the main repository, the developer could `git fetch frontend-only` and `git cherry-pick` or `git rebase` the changes in.  For pushing back to frontend he'd need to be careful to make those changes only a branch that's based on `frontend-only`, but it's probably easier than managing patches.

Comment: @Mark: But the two repos have no history in common. You mean I could fetch from an unrelated repo in my repo, creating a second root in my local repo, from which I can cherry-pick what I need to my local branches?

Comment: @VonC: yes, exactly - it doesn't really matter if there's no history in common if you're just doing `git cherry-pick` (or a carefully chosen `git rebase` command)...

Comment: @Mark: so that would work also for publishing local evolution to frontend files to the second repo, then? No need for patches, that particular branch could be pushed directly to the second repo.

Comment: @VonC - thanks. This was actually an approach I was slightly hesitant on going forward with, but I guess it is the only practical way to do so as of now? It would have been so much more convenient if I could set permissions for users to have r/w access to certain files or folders in my private repo, as opposed to having to create a new private repo!

Comment: @bvi: since your repo in on GitHub, there isn't much you can do in tern of access rights. Should your repo have been on a server you could manage, then a gitolite ssh-based layer might have been possible in order to manage r/w *push* rights, but even then, that would have involved cloning the *full* repo history (and having access at least *read* access to everything) by the developers. Which wasn't what you wanted. A new independent repo is a much more secure solution. With direct pull/push by you in/from your repo, it is even convenient.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is probably to have your designers fork your repository on github.  They just push their changes to their github repository and and click "Pull Request" when they want you to merge in their work.  You could then have a small script that you run in your local copy that:

1. Checks that you're on `master` (or whatever your main branch is)
2. Runs `git fetch web-designer-one`
3. Checks that `git diff --name-only master web-designer-one/master` only contains files that you allow that person to change
4. If that's fine, runs `git merge web-designer-one/master`

(I was interpreting "has access to" to mean "allow them to change", but perhaps I misunderstand - if you don't want them to even be able to see the other files then [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114381/is-it-possible-to-open-up-only-certain-files-folders-in-my-private-github-repo-fo/5114479#5114479) is better.)

Comment: A good solution for general repositories, but it seems from the quest that he doesn't want the designers to even have read access to the core app (as it's in a private repository).

Comment: Well, I appreciate the sentiment, but I didn't answer. ;)

Comment: @VonC - I would prefer that the designers not have even read access to the meat of my application; only to the relevant frontend files that they would need to modify, nothing moer.

Comment: @bvi: then the double repos approach I propose in my answer should suit you.

Comment: @bvi: OK, +1 to @VonC from me :)

Comment: @Mark: thank you. +1 for mentioning the other possibility, should the access to the full repo had been possible.